# lotus notes opens new blank email to same recipient after sending an email

Tags: email, lotus-notes

This one is pretty much as the description. My new company uses Lotus Notes and when i send an email to a recipient, it sends the email fine but then opens up a new blank email, to the same recipient with no subject or body.

We're pretty sure it's a config item somewhere, but cant see it. Has anyone encountered this before or does anyone know where to look?

The setup is: Lotus Notes 8.5 on Windows 7.

Comment: Does this only happen to you or is happening to everyone?

Comment: only happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out that this is indeed default behaviour.

https://qp.research.ibm.com/help/help8_client.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/b5ae0618dad4d3fa8525760900121980?OpenDocument

It looks like the shortcut i was looking for is Shift + ESC.